# Warning! ActionDispatch::Session::CacheStore failed to save session. Content dropped. in logfile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, heroku, memcached

I'm running a Rails 4 application and I'm seeing this in my production logs on Heroku.  I see it frequently and some users are reported getting logged out and I don't see anything in the logs that would indicate why it's happening.  I don't see any information from dalli that it cannot save.  For most users, it works just fine. Any tips on how to hunt this down?

**Error Message in Production Logs**

```
Warning! ActionDispatch::Session::CacheStore failed to save session. Content dropped.
```

**My configuration in production**

```
  config.cache_store = :dalli_store,
      (ENV["MEMCACHIER_SERVERS"] || "").split(","),
      {:username => ENV["MEMCACHIER_USERNAME"],
       :password => ENV["MEMCACHIER_PASSWORD"],
       :failover => true,
       :socket_timeout => 1.5,
       :socket_failure_delay => 0.2
      }

  config.session_store = :mem_cache_store
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem that was creating this error, I'm using a custom header variable to set the session ID and the client was sending nil which was causing rack to not be able to store to a nil session ID. I wrapped the call in a blank? check to ensure it's only set if there is a valid value and that fixed my issue.

```
if(!request.headers["Session"].blank?)
  request.session_options[:id] = request.headers["Session"]
end
```